# Looking how to use Functions with Functions, using prototype

Tags: javascript

I'm just kind of horsing around, trying to mimick certain jQuery functions (trying to write the vanilla `javascript` for the jQuery functions) I've made up this here

```
function ezWork(element) {
    if (typeof element === 'string') {
        document.getElementById(element);
        console.log('Got element');
    }
}


ezWork.prototype.on = function(event, callback) {
    if (typeof event === 'string') {

        if (event === 'click') {
            if(window.addEventListener) {
                element.addEventListener('mousedown', callback);
                alert('addEventListener called');
            } else if (window.attachEvent) {
                element.attachEvent('onmousedown', callback);
            } else {
                element.onmousedown = callback;
            }
        }
    }
}

ezWork('click').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Worked');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aJmMa/

I'm just curious why I get .on is not defined (I'm doing this off how I think it should be done, and not whether or not if I know this is the proper way to do this, I'm just trying to learn, what is the correct way of doing what I'm trying to do to add functions to functions?)

Thanks a lot for the help!

The error I get now is, '.on' is not defined.

Comment: Well, `ezWork` doesn't look like a constructor. For that you need to create a new instance.

Comment: *ezWork* doesn't inherit from its own prototype, but from its constructor's prototype (i.e. from *Function.prototype*, which inherits from *Object.prototype*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var ezWork = (function(win, doc) {

  // Constructor
  function EzWork(element) {
    this.element = this._init(element);
  }

  EzWork.prototype = {
    _init: function(element) {
      return doc.getElementById(element);
    },

    on: function(event, callback) {
      // simplified...
      this.element.addEventListener(event, callback);
    }
  };

  // Shortcut to create a new instance without using 'new'
  return function(element) {
    return new EzWork(element);
  };

}(window, document));

ezWork('click').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('Worked');
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/oquduf/2/edit

Comment: It just grabs your element by id, that way you don't pollute the constructor. The underscore means "private" although it's really public, just a convention.

Comment: Thanks this works great, does ezWork default to the EzWork.prototype because it is the actual function inside the function? Does this also cache document and window for speed? Or did you just want something shorter than typing document and window?

Comment: Yup and yup, you got it. `win` and `doc` is for convenience but it is cached.

Comment: Thanks I'm gonna go play around with this layout, (again to mimick playing around with jquery) I should be able to do a lot more in the EzWork than just returning an element right? Like using regex to determine whether they put a # or . for class and id, also is _init: a reserved keyword for prototype? Last question I have :)

Comment: Of course, you can get multiple elements by changing it to `return [].slice.call(doc.querySelectorAll(selector));` and use it like `ezWork('div.class, p#id')`, just like jQuery.

Comment: `init` is not reserved, just convention. jQuery has an `init` method as well.

Answer (score 0):

Because `ezWork()` does not return an instance of `ezWork`. In fact, it doesn't return *anything*.  once you fix that, you'll find that `element` is undefined.  You'll have to add it and access it as a property.

```
function ezWork(element) {
    if (!(this instanceof ezWork)) {
        return new ezWork(element);
    }
    if (typeof element === 'string') {
        element = document.getElementById(element);
        console.log('Got element');
    }
    this.element = element;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aJmMa/1/